# Concatenate object's properties of variable length of a C# object into a new property of the object

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays

Having [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50043790/concatenate-objects-properties-of-variable-length-of-a-javascript-object-into-a/) problem solved in JavaScript, I'm trying to do the same using C# for a C# object, not a JSON.

Basically, the JS solving looks like this:

```
myObject.myObject.forEach(arr => {
 arr.prop = arr.parameters.reduce((res,obj)=> res+obj.special, '')
})
```

so I tried to do it like:

```
foreach (array arr in myObject.myObject)
{
    arr.prop = arr.parameters.reduce();
}
```

I didn't find any function like the JS `reduce` in C#.

Do you have any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: reduce == aggregate in .NET

Comment: Leo Messi, really? Get life buddy! hold your name proudly. Can you show us your c# code, what you have and what you need to achieve. right now it sounds like, "can you translate this for me?"

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by first getting all fields or Properties from an object via Reflection

```
var fields = myObject.GetType().GetFields();
```

then you pull all current values from those fields and make strings of it

```
var values = fields.Select(e => e.GetValue(myObject)?.ToString());
```

and after that, just aggregate the values

```
var allFieldsInOne = values.Aggregate((e,f) => e + f);
```